# FTP through Dreamweaver not working while Filezilla is fine

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver, godaddy

Dreamweaver FTP is not working for a site hosted on a particular server (Go Daddy in this instance) but using Filezilla FTP works.

Tested on another server (Rackspace) and both Dreamweaver and Filezilla managed to upload files fine.

Why would Dreamweaver be throwing a fit and not allow uploads via FTP to a certain webhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to check "Use Passive FTP" ... I would have tried this before asking if I had seen the option but Dreamweaver doesn't show it by default until you go into advanced settings.

Comment: hi JD, i am having the same problem. But with cs5.5 in site-setup and more options, i have check passive FTP but still DMW doesn't work and filezilla does? btw: only with one server